# Usando email de formulário no AddAdress

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Estou com um problema em enviar e-mail com o **`AddAdress`** no meu arquivo [php](/questions/tagged/php) que está recebendo os dados do formulário [html](/questions/tagged/html).

Já tentei de tudo aqui mas não funciona ='(

Detalhando a situação:

Recebo o endereço para o qual desejo enviar o e-mail aqui:

```
$Email                      = $_POST["Email"];


// Funciona normal, até uso em outros pontos no código e a string está perfeita

$mail->AddAddress($Email);

// Aqui não pega, mas caso eu coloque a string funciona.
```

---

Teste inicializar uma variável pra testar assim:

```
$teste = "email@teste.com";
$mail->AddAddress($teste, $Nome);
```

Pegou normal.

---

Teste pegar o valor da variável **`$Email`** mas também não pegou, dessas duas formas:

```
$teste = "$Email";
$teste = $Email.
```

Enfim não sei mais o que fazer, o código está certo mas o problema é que não consigo usar o e-mail colocado no formulário =/

Answer (score 0):

Mano não sou ninja em PHP mas quem sabe te dou uma luz, no meu esta assim,

```
$destinatario = (isset($_POST['destinatario'])) ? $_POST['destinatario']: 'contato@system.com.br';

// Endereço do e-mail do destinatário

$mail->addAddress($destinatario);
```

Ele envia normal para meu email